# JSON Array or Object Error in Android

Tags: android, json

I have a string being returned from a HttpClient called data.

```
Data = {"result":[{"id":"2","contextID":"1","name":"Kitchen","image":"81"},
{"id":"1","contextID":"1","name":"Living Room","image":"18"},
{"id":"3","contextID":"1","name":"Toilet","image":"75"}]}
```

I am then performing this code:

```
resultArray = new JSONArray (data);
```

and returning this JSONArray. However, I get a JSONException error:

```
JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Surely this is a JSONArray not a JSONObject? Or is it a JSONObject of JSONObjects? I'm pretty new to JSON and I'm wanting to loop through and create new Locations using these imported values. Is there an easy or established way of doing this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a json object with a JSONArray of JSONObjects inside of it.  { } means object and [] means array.  So you get the top level string as a JSON object, then get the results parameter as an array, then get each index into the results as an object (and you can get the parameters of those via getString, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`Data` is a JSONObject, and `Data["result"]` is a JSONArray that contains JSONObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Data is actually a `JSONObject` that contains a `JSONArray` named "result."  If you wanted to get the `JSONArray` you'd have to do the following:

```
JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray dataArr = dataObj.getJSONArray("result");
```

For future reference, since you're new to JSON, data inside {} braces is a JSONObject and data inside [] braces is a JSONArray.  Arrays and objects can be nested inside of each other and it's sometimes hard to read.  I recommend formatting your data if you need help reading it.  I personally use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to format and validate my data.  I'm not associated with the site in any way.  I just find it really useful.